# block request after 4 in 1 day

Tags: php

I just need helpw with db structure and logic : code part i will do myself

i am making some request sending syetem , where user can send upto 4 requet in day after that they will be able to send request next day

below is db structure i am using

Db structure:

```
userid | lastrequestsent | requestcount|
```

i am unble to figure out logic for flow of it

please guide me way to do this

Comment: It looks like you forgot to paste your code.

Comment: bro i need help with db structure and logic code i can do

Comment: .. What? Your question mentions "below is snippet I am using", but I don't see any code so I assume you forgot to paste it?

Comment: @saurav Increment the request count every time the request is sent.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I guess by `snippet` he means `Db structure`

Comment: yeah see i can increment but how to manage like block after count is set 4 , and again set count to 0 after 1 day

Comment: how to set counter 0 next that is important thing where i am stuck

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started. In my example I use a SQL database, noted the comments. The logic works, you just need to actually pull and save the values into the database.

```
<?php
$userid = 1;
// get the current saved data from the database by user, like below
// SELECT * FROM `requests` WHERE `userid` = '$userid'
// put database data into variables like below, example only
$lastrequestsent = $db->LastRequestSent;
$requestcount = $db->requestCount;

// if it is a new day, reset requestcount to 0, otherwise if not a new day, keep value
$requestcount = (date('Y-m-d') === date('Y-m-d',strtotime($lastrequestsent))) ? $requestcount : 0;

// if requestcount is less than 3
if ($requestcount < 3) {
  $lastrequestsent = date('Y-m-d'); // assigns the current date to lastrequestsent 
  $requestcount++; // increments requestcount by 1
  echo "You can still request today.";
  // update data into database
  // UPDATE `requests` WHERE `userid` = '$userid' SET `lastrequestsent` = '$lastrequestsent', `requestcount` = '$requestcount'
}
else {
  echo "You cannot request anymore today.";
}
?>
```